# HIViewSetZOrder equivalent in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

What is the equivalent of carbon function HIViewSetZOrder  in cocoa ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely only on view hierarchy (parents,childs) to layer your views. Overlapping views are a bad idea.

There is a - (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView method but in order to layer your views you'll have to remove/add them again.

Alternatives are to use NSWindow or Core Animation.